# Query each node's inner content

Tags: xml, t-sql, xquery

I know that I can do this -

```
declare @args xml = '<arg><value>hello</value></arg><arg><value>world</value></arg>';

select arg.value('value[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
from @args.nodes('//arg') args(arg);
```

But I'd like to do something like this (without the superfluous `<value>` tags) -

```
declare @args xml = '<arg>hello</arg><arg>world</arg>';

select arg.value('?', 'nvarchar(max)')
from @args.nodes('//arg') args(arg);
```

What's the right XQuery expression?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @args xml = '<arg>hello</arg><arg>world</arg>';

select arg.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
from @args.nodes('//arg') args(arg);
```